# Java.exe locking the file for some time after the file is created

Tags: java, file

I wrote a small program which compresses a tiff file and places the compressed one file in a separate folder "compressed"  , the new file that is generated is being locked by java.exe when i try to perform a action on it .

When I run the method manually then java.exe is not locking it but when i call that method through a web service call then it is getting locked , Any idea why this happens , but the locking is only for some time , after that I am able to delete it

Comment: How do you "run the method manually"? Via your IDE or console using a `public static void main`? If yes, then resources are auto-released upon exit of the program. That's why the file is not locked.

Comment: @cherouvim Via IDE , file is not getting locked , but i made it as a web service , so when the web service call is done then the file is getting locked for some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the Garbage Collector , while running from netbeans , I guess netbeans calls the garbage collector after every program execution but its not the case for Webservice calls , Issue resolved after calling GC explicitly from my code.

Comment: Not sure it is a GC issue.

Comment: @cherouvim Its a GC issue.

Comment: Because , here while creating a compressed image , I  aint creating a BufferedWriter or something , I am using javax.media.jai.JAI.create() method to create the image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the resource you used for writing the file.

For instance with a `FileWriter` and a `BufferedWriter`:

```
FileWriter fw = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    fw = new FileWriter(new File(outputFile));
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something with e
} finally {
    if(bw != null) {
        bw.close();  // release the resource
    }
}
```

Using try-with-resources, which automatically closes atfer the `try` block:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(new File(outputFile));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
    bw.write(content);
}
```

Comment: Because a BufferedWriter closes its enclosed stream when being closed, and because FileWriter has a construtor accepting a String, it's also possible to simply do `try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) { bw.write(content); }`.

Comment: I am closing the stream , It is the glassfish server that is locking the file for some time

Comment: @ChristianHujer, but then the `FileWriter` won't be closed if the `BufferedWriter` constructor throws an exception.  (This probably isn't much of a risk with `BufferedWriter`, but it can be a significant concern for other classes, so one has to think carefully about whether it's OK to do this.)